# Complete name for the type ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I just want to know the "absolute" name for the type which is represented by an ArrayList of String (`ArrayList<String>`).

For exemple, for Integer, the complete name is `java.lang.Integer`, so what's the equivalent for the `ArrayList<String>` ?

Thanks

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: When you have doubts like this check Oracle's documentation. Example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: For questions like this, javadoc is your friend. Go to google, in your case, type "Arraylist javado"c. The package where it belongs, class details, and other helpful details are available there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>`, the fully qualified name will be `java.util.ArrayList`. It won't change based on the type of data the list will hold.

Read up on [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more insight.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.String for String and java.util.List for list and java.util.ArrayList for arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.class.getName()`  gives `java.util.ArrayList` 
and similarly for String
`String.class.getName()`  gives `java.lang.String`
`

Answer (score 0):

The "absolute" (i.e. fully qualified) name of `ArrayList` is `java.util.ArrayList`, but I would say the fully qualified name of `ArrayList<String>` is:

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have that kind of "name" for `ArrayList<>` and `String` as follows.

```
 java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

But `ArrayList<WHAT_EVER>` fully qualified name is `java.util.ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

for String:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

for ArrayList:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

for the future, enter (in google) for example:

```
string java
```

or just go to:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

and search what you want.